# call METIS API via Java

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, graph-databases, database-partitioning, metis

I'm trying to partition a road network graph through Java. But I cannot come up with my own algorithm/code, I read that most of the experiments were using the METIS library to partition their graph "Road network graph". When I read the METIS documentation I couldn't find anything about the API calling or installing for java. However, I found that METIS could be implemented in Python. I mostly work in Java and I have no prior knowledge of C/C++ and python. Is there anyone who can suggest to me some idea on how I use the METIS for Java?